# Add CSS Class with Knockout Validator

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I want to add a CSS Class to a `select` element in my view, my view model has a property which I've extended using Knockout-Validation:

```
self.selectedRootCause = ko.observable().extend({
    required: true
});
```

Then my `select` is like so:

```
<form data-bind="submit: closeComplaint" method="post"> 
    <select data-bind="options: rootCauses, 
                            optionsText: 'RootCauseText', 
                            value: selectedRootCause, 
                            optionsCaption: 'Choose..',
                            validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 
                                                 'input-validation-error' }">
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Close Complaint" />
</form>
```

My `closeComplaint` function looks like so:

```
self.closeComplaint = function () {
    if (self.errors().length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("CloseComplaint")',
            data: new DetailsComplaintAdmin(self.currentComplaint(),
                                        self.selectedRootCause().RootCauseId
                ),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Just for completion, here is my `self.errors()` function:

```
self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
```

The problem is the class `input-validation-error` doesn't appear to be added to my `select` input when I submit my form? Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Checkout this [link](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration)

Its said that you have to set  `decorateElement` to `true` for applying CSS
classes to input tags. 
So when i apply that parameter globally it works :

```
ko.validation.configure({ 
    decorateElement : true
});
```

Checkout this jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/cxTZJ/)

**Note**: In more recent versions of the Knockout Validation library, the `decorateElement` configuration option has been renamed to `decorateInputElement`([details](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration))

Comment: Plus 1 for the mention of decorateInputElement

Comment: And the global configuration is done in `ko.validation.init` not `ko.validation.configuration`.